# Selecting the Opportunity Price Book

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebookentry

I'm still fairly new to Salesforce Apex and trying to figure out how to select a price book from the opportunity.

The reason being I have a trigger which adds in a product when the opportunity is created or edited. The problem is I've got two price books, so when I wan't to change the price book it has conflict as it want's to use the price book that the trigger is using and not the one on the opportunity.

Does anybody know best way or how I can make it select the opportunities price book rather than me setting one.

I've put the code below - Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Map<String,String> productMap = new Map<String,String>();

        if(checkRecursive.checkOneTimeForupdate()) {
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe :[Select id ,name,PriceBook2Id,PriceBook2.Name,Product2.name 
                                    from PriceBookEntry where PriceBook2.Name = 'Sales price in GBP'
                                    and  Product2.Family ='Delivery' and CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP' limit 999]){
                productMap.put(pbe.Product2.name,pbe.Id);

            }

            List<OpportunityLineItem> opLines = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLtmToDelete = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLtmTocheck = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

            List<Opportunity> OppsWithOplis = [select id, name, Delivery__c, Account.Distance_Between__c, Account.billingaddress,  
                                                    (select id, name, NotRemove__c, quantity, product2.Family 
                                                        from OpportunityLineItems  
                                                        where OpportunityId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND
                                                        product2.Family ='Delivery' AND
                                                        (NotRemove__c = True or NotRemove__c = False)
                                                    ) 
                                                   from Opportunity where 
                                                   Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND
                                                   Delivery__c != null AND 
                                                   Account.Distance_Between__c != null];

            //Loop through Opps only once
            for(Opportunity opp : OppsWithOplis){
                system.debug('***** Inside existing code.');
                if(Account.billingaddress != null && opp.Delivery__c != '-none-') {
                    Product_Distance_Amount__c pdistanceStg = Product_Distance_Amount__c.getValues(opp.Delivery__c);

                    if(productMap.containskey(opp.Delivery__c)) {
                        //Loop through related Oplis only once
                        for(OpportunityLineItem opli : opp.OpportunityLineItems){
                            if(opli.NotRemove__c == True){
                                oppLtmTocheck.add(opli);
                            }else if(opli.NotRemove__c == False){
                                oppLtmToDelete.add(opli);
                            }
                        }

                        OpportunityLineItem  newItem = new OpportunityLineItem();
                        newItem.OpportunityId = Opp.id;
                        newItem.PriceBookEntryid = productMap.get(opp.Delivery__c);
                        newItem.quantity = 1;
                        if(opp.Account.Distance_Between__c == '0-25') newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X0_25_miles__c;
                        else if(opp.Account.Distance_Between__c == '26-75') newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X26_75_miles__c;
                        else if(opp.Account.Distance_Between__c == '76-150') newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X76_150_miles__c;
                        else if(opp.Account.Distance_Between__c == '151-250') newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X151_250_miles__c;
                        else if(opp.Account.Distance_Between__c == '250-350') newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X250_miles__c;
                        else newItem.UnitPrice = pdistanceStg.X350_miles__c;
                        if(oppLtmTocheck.isEmpty()) opLines.add(newItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!oppLtmToDelete.isEmpty())  delete oppLtmToDelete;

            if(!opLines.isEmpty()) insert opLines; 
        }    
    }


}
```

Comment: All you've really got to do is set the `PricebookId` field on your `Opportunity` (and then perform a DML update), but I'm not entirely sure that's what you want to do. Changing pricebooks, if memory serves, will delete all the existing line items on that opportunity. I'm pretty sure that you'd need to have all your products available in a common pricebook.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is if I set the price book on the opportunity and save it. The trigger is trying to add a product so when I change it it comes up with this error
execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [PricebookEntryId] Trigger.DeliveryProduct: line 884, column 1
Think this is because of this line of code PriceBook2.Name = 'Sales price in GBP'

Comment: All the products are in all the price books but when I change the price book on the opportunity to 'Sales Price in (Old)' it wants to change it back to 'Sales Price in GBP' so it won't allow me to edit the opportunity. 

I just wondered if it could look at all the prices books and choose dependent on the price book in the opportunity